# Using timeUpdate and currentTime

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to use timeUpdate and currentTime to be able to show and hide a div at a certain time when a video is playing.

I have managed to get something working, however it seems to show and hide for each second I want it to show for.

I have attached the code below... is there any way i can have it shown without it showing and hiding for each second?

```js
var video_one = document.getElementById('video_one'),
 video_two = document.getElementById('video_two'),
 video_one_wrapper = document.getElementById('video_one_wrapper'),
 video_two_wrapper = document.getElementById('video_two_wrapper'),
 play_button = document.getElementById('play_button');

 // add event listener to play button
 play_button.addEventListener('click', play_videos);

 // run function on click
 function play_videos() {
  video_one.play();
  video_two.play();
 }

 var switch_button = document.getElementById('switch_button');

 switch_button.addEventListener('click', switch_videos);

 function switch_videos() {
  console.log('click');

  if(video_one_wrapper.classList.contains('video_active')) {
   console.log('it contains');
   video_one_wrapper.classList.remove('video_active');
   video_two_wrapper.classList.add('video_active');
  } else if(video_two_wrapper.classList.contains('video_active')) {
   video_two_wrapper.classList.remove('video_active');
   video_one_wrapper.classList.add('video_active');
   console.log('it doesnt')
  }
 }

 video_one.addEventListener("timeupdate", message_one);
 video_two.addEventListener("timeupdate", message_two);

 var message_one = document.getElementById("message_one"),
  message_two = document.getElementById("message_two");


 function message_one() {
  // if time between 10s and 20s
  if(this.currentTime > 1 && this.currentTime < 20) {

   if(message_one.classList.contains("message_hide")) {
    message_one.classList.remove("message_hide");
   } else {
    message_one.classList.add("message_hide")
   }
  }
 }

 function message_two() {
  // if time between 10s and 20s
  if(this.currentTime > 1 && this.currentTime < 20) {

   if(message_two.classList.contains("message_hide")) {
    message_two.classList.remove("message_hide");
   } else {
    message_two.classList.add("message_hide")
   }
  }
 }
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #FFF;
 background-color: #242424;
}

.landing {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}

.landing_wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.title_wrapper {
 text-align: center;
}

.title_wrapper > h1 {
 font-size: 46px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 color: #FFF;
}

.title_wrapper > button {
 background-color: #FFF;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 10px 20px;
}

video {
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 100;
}

.video {
 position: relative;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}

.video_wrapper {
 position: relative;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.video_item {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 99;
}

.switch_wrapper {
 z-index: 100;
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
}

.video_element {
 z-index: 100;
}

.message_wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 200;
}

.message_hide {
 display: none;
}

.video_one {
 z-index: 0;
}

.video_two {
 z-index: 0;
}

.video_active {
 z-index: 10;
}

.video_three {
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Title Here</title>
 <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
 <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>

<body>

 <div class="landing">
  <div class="landing_wrapper">

   <div class="title">
    <div class="title_wrapper">
  <h1>Title Here</h1>
  <button id="play_button">Start</button>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="video">

 <div class="switch_wrapper"><button id="switch_button">Switch</button></div>

  <div class="video_wrapper">



   <div id="video_one_wrapper" class="video_item video_active">

    <div id="message_one" class="message_wrapper message_hide"><h1>Hello Video 1</h1></div>

    <video id="video_one" class="video_element" src="http://vid1308.photobucket.com/albums/s607/Billy_Adam_Skinner/girl_1_zps8ud1zuxh.mp4" loop >

   </div>
   <div id="video_two_wrapper" class="video_item">

    <div id="message_two" class="message_wrapper message_hide"><h1>Hello Video 2</h1></div>

    <video id="video_two" class="video_element" src="http://vid1308.photobucket.com/albums/s607/Billy_Adam_Skinner/boy_zpsugnp76od.mp4" muted loop>
   </div>

  </div>



 </div>

  <script src="js.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeupdate event occurs when the playing position of an audio/video has changed.
Example. When video is playing . This function `message_one` always is calling every time (second) when video is playing. I will give you example step

1. `currentTime = 1` s
2. `message_one` function called
3. `message_one` element doesn't contain class "message_hide"
4. `message_one` element add class "message_hide"
5. `currentTime` increases to 2s
6. `message_one` function called
7. `message_one` element now is containing class "message_hide" .
8. `message_one.classList.add("message_hide")` this will call. it makes message hide

And again when currentTime update it will change, it makes the message show hide loop

Your current function

```
function message_one() {
  // if time between 10s and 20s
  if (this.currentTime > 1 && this.currentTime < 20) {

    if (message_one.classList.contains("message_hide")) {
      message_one.classList.remove("message_hide");
    } else {
      message_one.classList.add("message_hide")
    }
  }
}
```

I suggest one way to resolve

```
if (this.currentTime > 0 && this.currentTime < 20) {
    message_two.classList.remove("message_hide");
 }
 else {
    message_two.classList.add("message_hide")
 }
```